# How to access Marketing cloud for learning

Tags: marketing-cloud

How we can access Marketing cloud, so as to see its recent updates and play with it without paying for actual license?

There is option of marketing user in Developer edition, however not able to use marketing studio n all.

So any way/trick to achieve it, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Marketing Cloud developer accounts are only available to **registered Partners** at this time. If you are a Salesforce Partner, then you can request a free Marketing Cloud developer account by creating a case on the [Partner Portal](https://partners.salesforce.com/newPartnerCase?subtopic=Partner%20Benefits).

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a developer edition (similar to the ones for Salesforce.com). Unfortunately this has been discontinued and the only way to use it is by having an actual subscription, or working with someone that has one.